# Plotting Candlestick at Tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, candlestick-chart

Does anyone know how to plot a simple candlestick at tkinter? I am trying to use the code from the following [MatPlotLib website](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/finance_demo.html) and run it at Sublime Text 3. However, after so many attempts the tkinter won't open, and I keep receiving this warning:

```
2016-07-26 13:38:46.546 Python[88018:4981017] -[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x106c42df0
2016-07-26 13:38:46.574 Python[88018:4981017] An uncaught exception was raised
2016-07-26 13:38:46.574 Python[88018:4981017] -[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x106c42df0
2016-07-26 13:38:46.574 Python[88018:4981017] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff917474f2 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff966a573c objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff917b11ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff916b7571 ___forwarding___ + 1009
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff916b70f8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Tk                                  0x0000000101677948 TkpInit + 476
    6   Tk                                  0x00000001015f2a6e Tk_Init + 1799
    7   _tkinter.cpython-35m-darwin.so      0x00000001003f0dcd Tcl_AppInit + 77
    8   _tkinter.cpython-35m-darwin.so      0x00000001003ee7d9 _tkinter_create + 889
    9   Python                              0x0000000100065479 PyCFunction_Call + 233
    10  Python                              0x00000001000f1631 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 36305
    11  Python                              0x00000001000f2510 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2368
    12  Python                              0x00000001000f038b PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 31531
    13  Python                              0x00000001000f2510 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2368
    14  Python                              0x00000001000f2617 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 71
    15  Python                              0x000000010004031a function_call + 186
    16  Python                              0x000000010000d713 PyObject_Call + 99
    17  Python                              0x00000001000286fc method_call + 140
    18  Python                              0x000000010000d713 PyObject_Call + 99
    19  Python                              0x0000000100082a01 slot_tp_init + 81
    20  Python                              0x0000000100079624 type_call + 212
    21  Python                              0x000000010000d713 PyObject_Call + 99
    22  Python                              0x00000001000ec852 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 16370
    23  Python                              0x00000001000f2510 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2368
    24  Python                              0x00000001000f2671 PyEval_EvalCode + 81
    25  Python                              0x000000010012083e PyRun_FileExFlags + 206
    26  Python                              0x0000000100120adf PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 447
    27  Python                              0x0000000100139858 Py_Main + 3512
    28  Python                              0x0000000100000e32 Python + 3634
    29  Python                              0x0000000100000c84 Python + 3204
    30  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
2016-07-26 13:38:46.575 Python[88018:4981017] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x106c42df0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff917474f2 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff966a573c objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff917b11ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff916b7571 ___forwarding___ + 1009
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff916b70f8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Tk                                  0x0000000101677948 TkpInit + 476
    6   Tk                                  0x00000001015f2a6e Tk_Init + 1799
    7   _tkinter.cpython-35m-darwin.so      0x00000001003f0dcd Tcl_AppInit + 77
    8   _tkinter.cpython-35m-darwin.so      0x00000001003ee7d9 _tkinter_create + 889
    9   Python                              0x0000000100065479 PyCFunction_Call + 233
    10  Python                              0x00000001000f1631 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 36305
    11  Python                              0x00000001000f2510 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2368
    12  Python                              0x00000001000f038b PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 31531
    13  Python                              0x00000001000f2510 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2368
    14  Python                              0x00000001000f2617 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 71
    15  Python                              0x000000010004031a function_call + 186
    16  Python                              0x000000010000d713 PyObject_Call + 99
    17  Python                              0x00000001000286fc method_call + 140
    18  Python                              0x000000010000d713 PyObject_Call + 99
    19  Python                              0x0000000100082a01 slot_tp_init + 81
    20  Python                              0x0000000100079624 type_call + 212
    21  Python                              0x000000010000d713 PyObject_Call + 99
    22  Python                              0x00000001000ec852 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 16370
    23  Python                              0x00000001000f2510 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2368
    24  Python                              0x00000001000f2671 PyEval_EvalCode + 81
    25  Python                              0x000000010012083e PyRun_FileExFlags + 206
    26  Python                              0x0000000100120adf PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 447
    27  Python                              0x0000000100139858 Py_Main + 3512
    28  Python                              0x0000000100000e32 Python + 3634
    29  Python                              0x0000000100000c84 Python + 3204
    30  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
[Finished in 1.3s with exit code -6]
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
from tkinter import * 

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, WeekdayLocator,\
    DayLocator, MONDAY
from matplotlib.finance import quotes_historical_yahoo_ohlc, candlestick_ohlc


class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)

        date1 = (2004, 2, 1)
        date2 = (2004, 4, 12)


        mondays = WeekdayLocator(MONDAY)        
        alldays = DayLocator() 
        weekFormatter = DateFormatter('%b %d')  
        dayFormatter = DateFormatter('%d') 

        quotes = quotes_historical_yahoo_ohlc('INTC', date1, date2)
        if len(quotes) == 0:
            raise SystemExit

        fig = Figure(figsize = (7.5, 4.5), dpi = 100)
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)


        ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mondays)
        ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(alldays)
        ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(weekFormatter)
        candlestick_ohlc(ax, quotes, width=0.6)
        ax.xaxis_date()
        ax.autoscale_view()
        plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side = TOP,  fill = BOTH,  expand = False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.geometry("800x600+51+51")
    app.title("Candlestick")
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: what isn't working? your code gives me a nice candlestick plot

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Does it crash? Does it display the wrong data?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. I have updated the description of the question. So when I run the code, the tkinter window won't appear and I receive a long list of warning.